# How can I paginate when ordering by `date_bin`?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, row, pagination

I have the following query

```sql
SELECT u.update_time, about_me
FROM users u
ORDER BY date_bin('14 days', u.update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56.471560Z') DESC, LENGTH(u.about_me) DESC, u.user_id;
```

I get the following:

| update_time | about_me |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-06 19:59:56.771388 +00:00 | Hello! How are you? |
| 2023-04-02 03:31:09.833925 +00:00 | Hello!!! |
| 2023-04-06 00:36:26.822102 +00:00 | Hello! |
| 2023-04-05 19:16:20.968274 +00:00 | Hey! |

I now want to only get everything after the 3rd row. So I would do the following:

```sql
SELECT u.update_time, about_me
FROM users u
WHERE (date_bin('14 days', u.update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56.471560Z'), LENGTH(u.about_me)) <
      ('2023-04-07 03:05:24.990233 +00:00', 6)
ORDER BY date_bin('14 days', u.update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56.471560Z') DESC, LENGTH(u.about_me) DESC, u.user_id;
```

But the issue is that I'm still getting the exact same results, it's as if the WHERE isn't working. How can I paginate the query?

Comment: The problem is that you start the date bin at `now()`, which is greater the next time you call it, so the result of the function will be greater too. Use a constant timestamp instead. Also, you should also compare with the previous `user_id` to break ties.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe oh! That makes sense!! If you make this an answer, I'll mark it at solved!

Comment: Hey @LaurenzAlbe I just tested this and it doesn't work.

Comment: Saying "dosen't work" is saying nothing. Please edit your question, add what you tried, what happened and how that diverges from what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your case straight. First, a proper table definition. We need a PK or similar to break ties unambiguously:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id     int PRIMARY KEY
, update_time timestamptz NOT NULL
, about_me    text NOT NULL
);
```

The column `update_time` is type `timestamptz`. Keep working with `timestamptz`, and don't mix with `timestamp`.

Next, sample rows to exhibit possible problems:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES
  (1, '2023-04-06 19:59:56.771388 +00:00', 'Hello! How are you?')
, (3, '2023-04-02 03:31:09.833925 +00:00', 'Hello!!!')
, (2, '2023-04-06 00:36:26.822102 +00:00', 'Hello!')
, (4, '2023-04-05 19:16:20.968274 +00:00', 'Hey!')
, (5, '2023-04-02 03:31:09.833925 +00:00', 'Same len')
, (7, '2023-05-02 03:31:09.833925 +00:00', 'Later!!!')
, (6, '2023-03-02 03:31:09.833925 +00:00', 'Earlier!')
;
```

Proper base query:

```
SELECT user_id, update_time, about_me
FROM   users u
ORDER  BY date_bin('14 days', update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56+0') DESC
        , length(about_me) DESC
        , user_id DESC;  -- !
```

`'2023-04-07 23:11:56+0'` being your arbitrary (but constant!) time anchor.

Notably, you added `user_id` as 3rd expression to `ORDER BY` to break ties. That's good. But if you want to keep using [***Row Constructor Comparison***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON), all 3 expressions must share the **same sort direction**. All `ASCENDING` or all `DESCENDING`. (Else it gets more complex and expensive.) See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982895/939860)
- [How to form a WHERE condition matching multiple ORDER BY items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009745/939860)

Also, add `user_id` to the `SELECT` list. It's essential for your pagination.

Then, to get the 1st page with an example page size of ***3***:

```
SELECT user_id, update_time, about_me
FROM   users u
ORDER  BY date_bin('14 days', update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56+0') DESC
     , length(about_me) DESC
     , user_id DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

2nd page:

```
SELECT user_id, update_time, about_me
FROM   users u
WHERE (date_bin('14 days', update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56+0'), length(about_me), user_id)
    < ('2023-03-25 00:11:56+01', 8, 5)
ORDER  BY date_bin('14 days', update_time, '2023-04-07 23:11:56+0') DESC
     , length(about_me) DESC
     , user_id DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ON5GXBHt)

`('2023-03-25 00:11:56+01', 8, 5)` being derived from the last row of the first page.

`'2023-03-25 00:11:56+01'` is the result of the `date_bin()` expression. You might add it to the `SELECT` list for simplicity. (I added it in the fiddle.)

Since your `date_bin()` expression uses an arbitrary time anchor (and interval?), using an index is sophisticated, but still possible. Work with the lower / upper bounds of possible `date_bin()` values ...

These two `timestamptz` values are exactly the same:

```
'2023-03-24 23:11:56+00'
'2023-03-25 00:11:56+01'
```

The *display* depends on the `timezone` setting of your session, the *value* is the same. Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: How did you derive `2023-03-25 00:11:56+01` ? Looking at the fiddle. The `update_time` for the last row is `2023-04-02 04:31:09.833925+01`

Comment: It's the result of the `date_bin()` expression. You might add it to the `SELECT` list for simplicity.

Comment: That was amazing! and it worked! Thanks!!